# Reputation sharing between Microsoft forums and Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation

My 2 most favorite forum sites are the Microsoft forums as well Stack Overflow. I have spent a lot of time answering questions and building my reputation on the Microsoft forums and have recently started doing the same in Stack OverFlow.

It would be great if there was a reputation sharing feature between the 2 sites since they both have a very active community. Are there any plans for this?

Comment: Linking to your profile on MS Forums in your SO profile should be sufficient, IMO.

Comment: Welcome to Meta SO, @Shailen! Please don't be discouraged by your question's low score. Here, downvotes just mean "I don't want the team to implement the feature you requested," not "you asked a bad question."

Answer (score 14):

Stack Overflow is not a forum site. It's a Q&A site.

Sharing reputation between two entirely different kinds of sites doesn't sound like a very sustainable idea to me, even if the two sites share a similar concept of reputation.

Comment: Not to mention, Stack Overflow isn't a Microsoft technology fan site either. [It's a jQuery fan site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/137537), and jQuery isn't made by Microsoft, not that I know of anyway.

Comment: I agree. Reputation is not even shared between Stack Exchange sites; I don't see why the reputation should be shared between different sites such as Microsoft forums and Stack Exchange, which have also different objectives.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - Are you saying that jQuery is not the answer to this question? (`:P`)

Comment: I agree but note that reputation is shared between SU and its meta MSU (620, 620) while this is not true for SO and its meta MSO (8018, 186) which seems weird to me. I haven't noticed this yet for any of the other SE sites.

Comment: @Dan D.: MSO is the only meta site that doesn't share reputation with its parent site. Reputation is shared by every other site and its own per-site meta.

Comment: So what you're saying is, we should share rep with expertsexchange? :P